# Implications of Stationarity and Causality in AR model

Tags: time-series, stationarity, autoregressive

From my understanding, an AR(p) process is causal implying that the process can be written as an infinite sum of linear combinations of previous White Noise. So, graphically, would expect the time series to hover around the mean of the process.

However, I'm curious what does it mean when the AR(p) process is stationary but not causal? I.e, the roots lie within (but not on) the unit circle).

Comment: Causality usually depicted for two AR models, as in [Granger causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality). Not sure if we can raise an issue of causality for univariate AR models. The question might be that if we can have time-series that it is stationary and de-correlated at the same time.